# Difference between leave and leave of absence

Tags: meaning

What is the difference between “ take a leave” and “ take a leave of absence”?

Comment: Please could you include your research and what you think might be the answer?

Comment: I don’t know whether the employees take a leave or take a leave of absence!

Comment: When an employee _leaves_, it can be interpreted as them terminating employment at that business. A _leave of absence_ indicates the person will come back (it's not permanent)

Comment: It's the same thing: **leave** is an abbreviation of **leave of absence**. It's *permission* to be away from work or duty. This isn't the same meaning as "depart".

Comment: How about” John is on a 1-month leave”.

Comment: John has a 1-month leave of absence.

Comment: If someone 'takes their leave of' the people they are with, they say goodbye and go away. However, you seem to mean 'leave' in the sense of 'time away from work' in which case it is as @WeatherVane says.

Answer (score 1):

They mean the [same thing](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/leave%20of%20absence).

One meaning of the word "leave" is [permission](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/leave):

```
Definition of leave (Entry 2 of 3)
1a : permission to do something
```

This is the definition used in the phrase "leave of absence".  In this phrase, the word "leave" has nothing to do with the more common definition of "to go away from".  Note the common military expression "[AWOL](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/absent%20without%20leave)" or "Absent Without Leave" (i.e. Absent without permission.)

People love to abbreviate, and "Leave of Absence" is a mouthful, so people abbrieviated it to "Leave" so often that it became a second definition of the word "leave":

```
Definition of leave (Entry 2 of 3)
1a : permission to do something
b : authorized especially extended absence from duty or employment
```